# Centering ul list elements, even if the ul is wider that viewport (see explanation)

Tags: html, css

I have a `<ul>` that is centered and contains pictures, each displayed side by side in one row. The problem comes when the client resizes the browser or has a lower resolution than the width of the `<ul>` with the pics in it.

What I am trying to achieve is that the center of the `<ul>` always remains in the center of the browser (even when browser’s width is smaller than `<ul>`s width), and both sides of the `<ul>` should get cut outside of the browser equally.

Is this possible without using JavaScript?

Comment: Centre is a relative term. How wide is your list compared to the rest of the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, although you‘ll need an extra `<div>`, and this solution assumes the `<ul>` has a known, fixed height and width.

It’d be a bit easier to answer if we could see your code, but assuming you’ve got something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #pics {
        width: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #pics li {
        float: left;
    }
</style>
...
<ul id="pics">
    <li><img src="pic1.jpg"  width="100" height="100" /></li>
    <li><img src="pic2.jpg"  width="100" height="100" /></li>
    <li><img src="pic3.jpg"  width="100" height="100" /></li>
</ul>
```

Then you can get the centering behaviour you’re looking for like this::

```
<style type="text/css">
    #centerer {
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #pics {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -150px;
        width: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #pics li {
        float: left;
    }
</style>
...
<div id="centerer">
    <ul id="pics">
        <li><img src="pic1.jpg"  width="100" height="100" /></li>
        <li><img src="pic2.jpg"  width="100" height="100" /></li>
        <li><img src="pic3.jpg"  width="100" height="100" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup, this is the solution, I didn`t thinked of it.

Comment: Thanks alot (seems likt this box submits on enter :P)